# Can I benefit from a reactive library in this scenario?

Tags: java, reactor, rx-java

App 1 sends request to App 2. App 2 performs the following steps and returns the response to App 1. I am wondering if App 2 can benefit from using reactive libraries like RxJava, Reactor etc. If so, please explain how?

1. Send the HTTP Post requests to all the 7 data source services
2. Wait for the responses from them and parse all the responses
3. Merge all the responses
4. Return response to App 1

[image]

Comment: I know: you want to use `reactive` solution here, but I want to add some noise. In EIP it calls `split-aggregate` and Spring Integration provides that solution as out-of-the-box. In this case the splitter can send items to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` or, if you want, to the Reactor or just to the RingBuffer. Each `data source service` should send its result to the `aggregator` and the last one just sends merged response.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am familiar with EIP and have been using camel and spring integration for lot of years. But my question is specifically about the benefits of going reactive for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about as classic a use case for reactive libraries as you might find! :)

The key part of "reactive" architectures is that they can respond to events rather than wait for results. RxJava facilitates this via `Observable` and Reactor does this via several different mechanisms. In Reactor, you can use a plain `Reactor` and set a `replyTo` on the `Event`, you can use a `Stream` or a `Promise` to compose a chain of processing on values much like RxJava's `Observable`, you can use a `Processor` to do high-speed RingBuffer processing, or you can use a `ForkJoinPool` for doing simple fork/join style processing. That's a lot of options, for sure, but each one is designed to work in a particular use case without compromising for other use cases. Reactor the framework isn't a single, adjustable wrench. It's a set of wrenches sized exactly for what you need.

In this particular case the important part is the parallelism achieved by doing lots of work *concurrently* since your datasource IO is presumably blocking the thread. RxJava has a pluggable execution model but it's fairly coarse-grained. One of Reactor's strengths is the efficient, fine-grained task dispatching support and the ease with which you can react to results.

Since your use case is pretty straightforward and much closer to a standard `ThreadPoolExecutor` situation, I might be tempted to use [the `ForkJoinPool` in Reactor 1.1](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/test/java/reactor/core/fork/ForkJoinPoolTests.java#L40) (which is brand new). The `ForkJoinPool` provides you with a single `Promise<ImmutableList<T>>` that joins the results of all the tasks you submit to the pool, which is backed by a standard `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It's basically a "reactive" wrapper around a standard thread pool so requires very little overhead but provides the flexibility of reacting to the completion of all submitted tasks. It's similar to RxJava's `Observable.merge()`.

Comment: +1. What if I want to continue even if some the 7 data sources have failed? Which one do you suggest for this scenarion: RxJava or Reactor? I'd like to delegate the thread mgmt to Spring's TaskExecutor abstraction. Is it possible in RxJava?

Comment: @Pangea It sounds like instead of `join` you might want the `fork` method instead, which gives you a `Stream` on which you can set a `when()` handler for errors and a "normal" `Consumer` for results. You'd have to keep track of the accounting yourself to know how many results you got back vs how many you expected. Reactor's Spring support also has an `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor` implementation that uses a Reactor `Dispatcher` that you configure. This is probably a better option for high volumes since a "normal" thread pool is pretty inefficient at high load.